# Make NextJS ignore .bablerc so only cypress and jest can use it for coverage

Tags: next.js, cypress

I Have a nextjs app, I want babel customization to run jest and cypress suite for testing, however when I configure babel.config.js file jest runs successfuly, but nextjs is also taking the configuration I dont want that, I want nextjs to ignore babel.config.js, How do I do that?